# Firefox triggers css load event twice

Tags: javascript, firefox

If you add a `load` event listener on a `HTMLLinkElement`, the `event` gets triggered twice in Firefox. (You can see the difference by running the snippet below in Firefox and in Chrome).

```js
var linkCss = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('link'));
linkCss.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
linkCss.setAttribute('href', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
linkCss.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
linkCss.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    console.log('CSS Loaded');
});
```

My current firefox version is: `68.0.1 (64 bit)`

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find if the expected behavior is defined in any spec, but note that if you prepare the element before inserting it into the DOM, there's only one *load* event fired:

```js
var linkCss = document.createElement('link');
linkCss.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
linkCss.setAttribute('href', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
linkCss.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
linkCss.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    console.log('CSS Loaded');
});

document.head.appendChild(linkCss)
```

If you start by appending the element to DOM, the first load is triggered when you set the "href" attribute, and the second load is triggered when you set the "type" attribute.

Comment: Thanks, at least now I know there's a reliable to listen for the load event.